# Rails - show errors in production mode in ENV

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to display errors in rails in production mode for only one site (i.e. by configuring something in the ENV)?

I have a app that is run in multiple instances. One of those instances is a production test site (exactly the same as a real version of the site, but with fake information in the DB). I would like dev style errors on this version of the app.

I know that I can make a change in my production.rb file, `config.consider_all_requests_local = true` but this change will affect all of my production sites.

Is there a way I can set it on a per instance basis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about...

```
config.consider_all_requests_local = !ENV[LOCAL_REQUESTS].nil?
```

Then, just set LOCAL_REQUESTS="true" in the environment in question.  Actually, it doesn't matter what you set the ENV to, this will evaluate anything as `true` and unset as `false`